# php array to string conversion does not work

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading content from xls file and storing each value in string seperating by `,`

Here is my code:

```
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('test.xlsx');
echo '<h1>$xlsx->rows()</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
echo '</pre>';
$result = array();
$result = $xlsx->rows();
var_dump($result);
$result=implode(",",$result);
echo $result;
```

NOw:

`print_r( $xlsx->rows() );` gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => karim
        )

)
```

`var_dump($result);` gives

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => string 'karim' (length=5)
```

next line

`echo $result;` gives error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure, it's not the `implode()` function returning that notice? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$result=implode(",",$result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should implode each row into a comma separated string in a new array, called result2

```
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('test.xlsx');
echo '<h1>$xlsx->rows()</h1>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
echo '</pre>';
$result = array();
$result = $xlsx->rows();
var_dump($result);
$result=
//echo $result;
$rows = count($result);
$result2 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
{
    $result2[$i] = implode(',',$result[$i]);
}
foreach($result2 as $value)
{
    echo $value.'<br/>';
}
```